# ErrorException (E_ERROR) rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: mysql, laravel

A trying to display data from two tables and am getting the above error message, can somebody help translate this error message?
Here is the Controller

```
public function index()
{
  $maintenances = DB::table('tenants')->select('tenants.lastname','tenants.firstname','maintenances.m_status','tenants.designation',      'maintenances.description','maintenances.building_section','maintenances.category','maintenances.reported_date')
        ->join('maintenances','maintenances.tenants_id','=','tenants.id')
        ->get();
    //dd($maintenances);
    return view('agent/maintenance_list', compact('maintenances', 'assetTenants', 'tenants'));
}
```

And view

```
@foreach($maintenances as $maintenance)
              <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <div class="checkbox-custom">
                    <input id="product-01" type="checkbox" value="01">
                    <label for="product-01" class="pl-0">&nbsp;</label>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>{{ $maintenance->designation }} {{ $maintenance->firstname }} {{ $maintenance->lastname }}</td>
                <td>{{ $maintenance->category }}</td>
                <td>{{ $maintenance->building_section }}</td>
                <td>{{ $maintenance->description }}</td>
                <td>{{ $maintenance->reported_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ $maintenance->m_status }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                  <div role="group" aria-label="Basic example" class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                    <a href="{{ url('agent/edit_maintenance', $maintenance }}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-success"><i class="ti-pencil"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
```

With the route

```
Route::get('maintenance_list', 'MaintenanceController@index')->name('/maintenance_list');
```

However, I noticed that once I remove the $maintenance variable from the url edit button, the page displays well. What can be the issue, for I don't understand the error message in the list

Comment: try it like this : `<a href="{{ url('agent/edit_maintenance', $maintenance->id }}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-success"><i class="ti-pencil"></i></a>`

Comment: what is result **dd( $maintenance)**;??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the whole `$maintenance` instead of something like `$maintenance->id`, hence the `object given` error:

```
<a href="{{ url('agent/edit_maintenance', $maintenance }}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-success"><i class="ti-pencil"></i></a>
```

Comment: I tried that but I get I get this  ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined property: stdClass::$id. The idea is to take the data to be edited to the edit page

Comment: I was using `->id` as an example, you will need to pass a unique parameter so when it goes to the `agent/edit_maintenance` url, it can pick up the parameter and determine exactly which 'maintenance' to edit. If you did want to use `->id` you will need to add `maintenances.id` in your `select` query (if  the `maintenances` table has an `id` column)